# Odoo8.0, cannot valid the csv file when try to import it

Tags: python, csv, import, barcode, odoo-8

I have problem when i was try to import .csv file. I was try to convert image to base64 and also i was try to create barcode by name csv file. The image it's success convert into base64 but the problem when i was try to create barcode by csv file name, i was always get error like :

```
Unknown error during import: <class 'openerp.exceptions.ValidationError'>: ('ValidateError', u'Field(s) `ean13` failed against a constraint: You provided an invalid "EAN13 Barcode" reference. You may use the "Internal Reference" field instead.') at row 2 Resolve other errors first
```

And this is my code:

```
files = []
text = ''"
data_text3 = []

header_column2 = ["id","product_variant_ids/ean13_barcode", "product_variant_ids/ean13", "ean13", "image", "ean13_barcode", "default_code", "product_variant_ids/default_code"]

number = 1 for file in os.listdir("gmbr/"):
    file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

    for n in str(number):
        directory_file = "gmbr/"+str(file)
        img = open(directory_file, 'rb').read()
        img_64 = base64.encodestr
        text = str(number)+","+str(name_product)+","+str(file_name)+","+str(file_name)+","+str(img_64+","+" "+","+" "+","+" ")
        number += 1
        data_text3.append(text)

with open('sample2.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t', dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(header_column2)
    for l in data_text3:
        writer.writerow(l.split(','))
```

Comment: it was already initialized

Comment: text variable is just for create header column in csv file. i store name of csv file into ean13. Take example the file is 123456789.jpg. first, i'll try to convert image to base64, after that the name of file i'll use for barcode, and i'll save it into ean13 column.

Comment: that is for "ean13_barcode", "default_code", "product_variant_ids/default_code". But, for ean13 i give value str(file_name).